# IntelliJ SDK for Plugin cannot find com.intellij.tasks

Tags: java, intellij-idea, sdk

This must be a painfully simple question but I am new to IntelliJ. I am running 14.1 community, and created a new plugin project.

This asked me to set the SDK, which is install of IntelliJ. No problem, I pointed it at the IDEA directory.

I grabbed some example source for creating a task repository from github.

When I try to import any of the actual classes in the Task jar, I get no classdef errors all over. [image]

It shows that it knows about `com.intellij.tasks` but all of the classes are missing.

What rookie mistake have I made?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to use `com.intellij.tasks.*` classes in plugin project, I've added `plugins/tasks/lib/tasks-*.jar` jars from IDEA installation to the classpath of SDK used to build plugin project.

[image: Project Structure screenshot]

Comment: Thanks victor! Good job digging up an old question :)